# Get transactionid in Postgres Advisory Lock within transaction

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, locking

I'm trying to get `transactionid` from `pg_locks` table when aquired Postgres advisory lock within transaction, but it's always `NULL`. I want to be sure that lock aquired witin transaction. Is there is a way to do it?

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(4);

SELECT transactionid
FROM pg_locks
WHERE locktype = 'advisory'
AND objid = 4;
```

Postgres container: `postgres:13.4-alpine`

Answer (score 2):

When you get a lock, your transaction is not yet holding a permanent id, you can see this:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(4);

SELECT *
FROM pg_locks;
```

There is no lock on hold in the list of locks transaction id.

From the doc:

> Every transaction holds an exclusive lock on its virtual transaction ID for its entire duration. If a permanent ID is assigned to the transaction (which normally happens only if the transaction changes the state of the database), it also holds an exclusive lock on its permanent transaction ID until it ends.

You can try to search for the locks you need by pid:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_locks WHERE pid = pg_backend_pid() AND locktype = 'advisory';
```

Answer (score 1):

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-locks.html) on `pg_locks` says:

> `transactionid xid`
>
> ID of the transaction targeted by the lock, or null if the target is
> not a transaction ID

In other words, `pg_locks.transactionid` is filled in when `locktype='transactionid'`.

The normal way to check if the lock is acquired is to test the return value of `pg_try_advisory_xact_lock`.

To test it after the fact looking up `pg_locks`, you could use the fact that it has been acquired by the current backend:

```
SELECT 1
FROM pg_locks
WHERE locktype = 'advisory'
AND pid = pg_backend_pid()
AND objid = 4;
```

Comment: Yeah, but I want to write integration tests and check if lock was really created on transaction-level, not session-level :\

Comment: @AntonKomarev: the distinction between transaction-level and session-level advisory locks doesn't seem to be exposed in views at the SQL level.